# Preload more than one image object using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does this kind of image preloading work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    new Image().src = "img/img1.png";
    new Image().src = "img/img2.png";
    new Image().src = "img/img3.png";
    new Image().src = "img/img4.png";
    new Image().src = "img/img5.png";
});
```

If not, can someone tell me how I should preload images after the page is loaded (using jQuery and JavaScript)?

Comment: try lazy loading plugin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464970/javascript-preload-images